# Reduction of cardiovascular mortality without affecting total mortality?

Tags: survival

Many interventional studies have found that the intervention reduced the primary end-point (a composite which includes cardiovascular mortality) without affecting total mortality. For example, the CANVAS randomized controlled clinical trial: Canagliflozin and Cardiovascular and Renal Events in Type 2 Diabetes. N Engl J Med 2017; 377:644-657. (https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1611925).
“Significantly fewer participants in the canagliflozin group than in the placebo group had a primary outcome event (the composite of death from cardiovascular causes, nonfatal myocardial infarction, or nonfatal stroke): 26.9 vs. 31.5 participants with an event per 1000 patient-years (hazard ratio, 0.86; 95% CI, 0.75 to 0.97; P<0.001 for noninferiority; P=0.02 for superiority) (Figure 2 and Figure 3).”
“Superiority was not shown for the first secondary outcome in the testing sequence (death from any cause; P=0.24), and hypothesis testing was discontinued. Therefore, estimates for the fatal secondary outcomes, including death from any cause (hazard ratio, 0.87; 95% CI, 0.74 to 1.01) and death from cardiovascular causes (hazard ratio, 0.87; 95% CI, 0.72 to 1.06), are not considered to be significant (Figure 2, Figure 3, and Figure 5).”
Does this finding imply that the intervention increased non-cardiovascular mortality? Should non-cardiovascular mortality be analyzed as a competing risk for cardiovascular mortality?

Comment: Can edit your post to add (1) a full reference t avoid link rot (2) a quote of the relevant section of the paper? Perhaps there simply wasn't a *significant* effect on total mortality, while there was one on cardiovascular mortality.

Comment: Please see the edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like yet another misapplication of statistical significance testing. This statement:

> Many interventional studies have found that the intervention reduced
>   the primary end-point (a composite which includes cardiovascular
>   mortality) without affecting total mortality.

is incorrect, at least in the example shown. It is true that overall mortality was not *significantly* reduced while cardiovascular mortality was, but, as Andrew Gelman has written, ["The difference between 'significant' and 'not significant' is not itself statistically significant".](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf) (Gelman, A, 2006, American Statistician, vol 60, p 328-333).

In this particular case, all the hazard ratios are very close.

Comment: Should non-cardiovascular mortality be used as a competing risk in the primary analysis? What will happen if we analyze non-cardiovascular mortality as a primary outcome without using cardiovascular mortality as a competing risk in survival analysis?

Comment: You can do any of those analyses - it depends on what you want to find out. What is your treatment intended to do?

Comment: This is only a general discussion. My point is that analyzing cardiovascular mortality without using non-cardiovascular mortality as a competing risk may be misleading.